# How to return null instead of exception in Oracle SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-administration

Is there some way for the function SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP return null or any other default value in a select query instead of throwing an exception in case of the SCN specified for the argument is too old in Oracle?

Comment: Can you create a simple wrapper function that catches the exception and returns `null`?  Or is there some reason that you have to use `scn_to_timestamp` directly?

Comment: I don’t think so. The goal is to find out the modification date of the rows in my tables. I only have read permission on the database, so I can’t create functions. If I get to add a pseudo column in my queries with this date, that would be great. The question is I don’t know which rows would generate an invalid SCN for the function SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP, and that makes Oracle throw an exception when the query is run.

Comment: Are you really using Oracle 10g and 11g?  Those are both pretty old.  If you were on 12.1, you could define an function inline in your SQL statement.

Comment: Yes. Actually I should run this query in Oracle 11g.

Comment: Then you probably can't get there from here.  You'd need to be able to define a new function that wrapped the call to `scn_to_timestamp`.  Or just use the SCN rather than the timestamp depending on what you are trying to accomplish.  Of course, I assume you're aware that the SCN is stored at the block level, not the row level, unless the table was build with `rowdependencies` (not the default).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm wondering if I could predict which are the valid SCNs to be sent to the function scn_to_timestamp, that probably could solve my question. Are these numbers available in any table?

Comment: If you have access to it, you could use the `smon_scn_time` table https://connor-mcdonald.com/2019/06/13/smon_scn_time-and-ora-8161-digging-deeper/